# Globally accessible attribute in UIViewController instances

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

In my RubyMotion app I would like to have a attribute, called `access_token`, accessible in every UIViewController instance.

All my controllers are either a subclass of `TableController` or `AppController`.

I tried creating an `attr_accessor` for `TableController` and `AppController`, though the problem is that assigning a new value will not be set for `TableController` or `AppController` at the same time.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use class variables for things like this, since iOS apps are not multi-user. Taking advantage of the fact that inherited classes share class variables, @@access_token will have the same value for all of your UIViewController subclasses (or your own subclass if you prefer).

I have something similar to this:

```
# Reopen and extend
class UIViewController # Actually I prefer UIViewController.class_eval do
  @@access_token = nil # This will have the same value for all UIViewController children

  def self.access_token=(value)
    @@access_token = value
  end

  def self.access_token
    @@access_token
  end
end
```

In reality, I would build a class that holds properties including and in addition to the token.

Comment: This is cool, but I still have one problem. `AppController` subclasses `UIViewController` and `TableController` subclasses `UITableViewController`...

Comment: UITableViewController inherits from UIViewController.

Answer (score 2):

Make `TableController` and `AppController` subclasses of a `Controller` class, and add the attribute in it.

Comment: This is so simple, that it's so genius that I wouldn't have thought about it this way.